# How can I force a navigation control to refresh?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my Clients form I have 2 textboxes (tbHHName, and tbHHID) and a navigation control (nav) displaying subforms/subreports.
When the user clicks tbHHName, a modal form opens to select which client to view.
Before switching clients, the form shows:

> tbHHName:  Client123
> nav: Account1, Account2, Account3

After switching to Client456, here's what it displays:

> tbHHName:  Client456
> nav: Account1, Account2, Account3

Here's what it *should* be displaying:

> tbHHName:  Client456
> nav: Account4, Account5, Account6

After the user clicks on one of the nav tabs it displays correctly, but I can't figure out how to force refresh the nav control without that click. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

All of the nav's subforms/subreports have the NavigationWhereClause set to: "[HH_ID] = tbHHID"

Below is the Form_Load, and the tbHHName_Click subs

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next
    
    'Set form recordsource
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM _HOUSEHOLDS WHERE HH_ID = " & GetSetting(AppName, Reg_JBGeneral, Reg_HH_ID, 0)
    
    'Apologize to users
    MsgBox "Please click on the Holdings tab again to refresh the data." & vbNewLine & _
    "      Sorry for the extra click," & vbNewLine & _
    "                            -MaybeOn8", , AppName
    
End Sub

Private Sub tbHHName_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    'open the form that sets new HH_ID value using the SaveSetting method
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Households_Select", WindowMode:=acDialog

    Form_Load
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, SO

Answer (score 0):

I tested with UNBOUND combobox sitting on main form to select filter parameter and NavigationWhereClause has criteria expression `HH_ID=Forms![NavForm]!Combo9`. Code in combobox AfterUpdate event:

```
Forms![NavForm]!NavigationSubform.Requery
```

Then I tested with code to change value of combobox and requery.

```
Forms!NavForm.Combo9 = 17
Forms!NavForm.NavigationSubform.Requery
```

This all works and does not involve changing RecordSource. Now just decide where to place code that changes control's value and requery subform.

Also, can use DoCmd.BrowseTo method to set focus on particular Navigation tab.

Comment: You'd think it would be that easy, but sorry, no dice.
I tried adding "Forms![Households]!NavigationSubform.Requery" to the end of the Form_Load sub, but it does nothing.

When the form loads the subform loads the data from before the recordsource change.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: The form was originally set to use a filter, but that caused massive bugs when on certain tabs.
Your first answer got me halfway to the solution though - the .FilterOn property instead of .Requery did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix. I tacked this onto the end of the Form_Load sub:

```
Forms("Households").NavigationSubform.Report.FilterOn = False
Forms("Households").NavigationSubform.Report.FilterOn = True
```

Even though there are mixed subforms and subreports in the navigation control, everything seems to load fine.